# Modified download url - firebase storage

Tags: google-cloud-storage, firebase-storage

I would need some method on the server side (cloud function) to give me a 'changing' url when an image is updated with same file name. Is that possible?

Background: I use the recent firebase extension to create thumbnails. When thumbnails are generated, I store the download urls on firestore for access in my mobile app

As per [difference between getSignedUrl() and getDownloadUrl()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58310843/difference-between-getsignedurl-and-getdownloadurl) I use getSignedUrl().

But this method gives me 'same' url even when the underlying image changes. And because the url is same the Widget (I use flutter) does not re-build and the modified image is not reflected

```
exports.thumbnailHandler = functions.storage.object().onFinalize(async (object) => {
  const contentType = object.contentType;
  const filePath = object.name;
  const fileBucket = object.bucket;
  const fileRef = admin.storage().bucket(fileBucket).file(filePath);

  const options = {
      action: 'read',
      expires: '12-31-2099'
    };

  fileRef.getSignedUrl(options).then(results => {
      var downloadUrl = results[0];
      console.log(downloadUrl); //This is same url everytime, even when image changes but with same file name
  }

}
```

Is there an alternative to signedUrl above something equivalent to downloadUrl from flutter sdk?

> Update This is the answer: This gives me the downloadUrl as I would from a client https://stackoverflow.com/a/53744579/11749006

Comment: So you're saying you want a URL that always fetches the latest version of an object, even after it changes in the storage bucket?

Comment: That is correct

Comment: This answer here gives me what I am looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53744579/11749006

Comment: Hi @Vinayakaram Nagarajan, good work finding the solution! Could you post the answer you found and accept it (https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/01/06/accept-your-own-answers/)? It will make it more visible and help someone with the same issue as you find the solution. Thanks!

Comment: Hi @Nahuel Varela, I did. But SO automatically converts to a comment

Comment: As you commented, this answer gives you what you are looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/a/53744579/11749006